# Remove character from file name in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and wanted to know if there's a way to remove a character from a file name.  The character I'm trying to remove is a dash "-" and sometimes there are 2 or 3 dashes in the file name.  Is it possible to have it rename files that have a dash in them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Get-Item .\some-file-with-hyphens.txt | ForEach-Object {
  Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -replace "-", "")
}
```

This question may be more suitable for SuperUser.

Comment: Can I use a wildcard for the Get-Item: 'Get-Item .\*.tif' ?

Comment: Yes, you can use wildcards in `Get-Item`. And you format code by putting it between backticks: \`code\`

Comment: Thank you, it worked!!  I'm trying to format code in the comments with backticks ' this is code '  - it doesn't seem to work, i feel like a newb.

Comment: Those are single quotes, not backticks. Not sure what keyboard layout you use, but on US keyboards the backtick is left of the <1>.

Answer (score 6):

To remove or replace characters in a file name use single quotes `'` and for "special" characters escape them with a backslash `\` so the regular expression parser takes it literally.

The following removes the `$` (dollar sign) from all file names in your current directory:

```
Get-Item * | ForEach-Object { rename-item $_ ($_.Name -replace '\$', '') }
```

the following is the same as above using the shorter alias for each command:

```
gi * | % { rni $_ ($_.Name -replace '\$', '') }
```

The following is removing the standard character "`Z`" from all file names in your current directory:

```
gi * | % { rni $_ ($_.Name -replace 'Z', '') }
```