# remove extraneous characters from a filename

Tags: powershell

I have been tasked a little above my head with taking a repository of files and removing excess garbage characters from the filename and saving the renamed file in a different directory folder.

An example of the filenames are:

```
100-expresstoll.pdf
1000-2012-09-29.jpg
10000-2014-01-15_14.03.22.jpg
10001-2014-01-15_19.05.24.jpg
10002-2014-01-15_21.30.23.jpg
10003-2014-01-16_07.33.54.jpg
10004-2014-01-16_13.33.21.jpg
10005-Feb 4, 2014.jpeg
10006-O'Reilly_Media,_Inc..pdf
```

First group of numbers at the beginning are record IDs and are to be retained along with the file's extension. Everything else between the record IDs and the file extension needs to be dropped.

For example, the final name for first three files would be:

```
100.pdf
1000.jpg
10000.jpg
```

I have read [Removing characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590931/remove-character-from-file-name-in-powershell) and [Rearranging filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118970/batch-rename-files-in-a-directory-by-rearranging-filenames) in addition to other postings, but the complexity of having a variable character length at the front, a variable number of intermediary characters to be removed and variable file extension types have really tossed this beyond my limited PowerShell reach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Regex / Powershell to rename files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574648/use-regex-powershell-to-rename-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach without regular expression. In both following examples is used  risk mitigation parameter `-WhatIf` for debugging purposes.

Rename files:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {
    $oldFile = $_.FullName
    $newName = $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] + $_.Extension
    if ($_.Name -ne $newName) {
        Rename-Item -Path $oldFile -NewName $newName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Rename and move files:

```
$newDest = 'D:\test'                       ### change to fit your circumstances
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {
    $oldFile = $_.FullName
    $newName = $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] + $_.Extension
    $newFile = Join-Path -Path $newDest -ChildPath $newName
    if ( -not ( Test-Path -Path $newFile ) ) {
        Move-Item -Path $oldFile -Destination $newFile -WhatIf
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`-replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) operator to do this kind of string manipulation:

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach {

    $old_name = $_.FullName
    $new_name = $_.Name -replace '([0-9]+).*(\.[^.]*)$', '$1$2'

    Rename-Item $old_name $new_name
}
```

The regular expression is the trick here:

1. `([0-9]+)` means match a series of digits (1 or more digits)
2. `.*` means match anything
3. `(\.[^.]*)` means match a period followed by any characters other than a period
4. `$` means that the match must reach the end of the string

The first and third are special in that they are surrounded by parentheses which means that you can use those values using the dollar notation (e.g. `$1`) in the replacement string.

Comment: Using `$new_name = ($_.Name -replace '([0-9]+).*$', '$1') + $_.Extension` would also work without having the regex find the extension string.

Comment: I'm well aware of the Extension property - thanks. The intent behind my answer is to demonstrate that the `-replace` operator can be used to solve string manipulations in general.

Comment: It is not a criticism. your answer shows the use of regex to get everything. My not is just one more way to skin the cat.

Comment: Indeed - I apologize if that came across as harsh.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most idiomatic way of solving this is as follows (assumes that all files of interest - and no others - are in the current dir.):

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -split '-')[0] + $_.Extension }
```

Add common parameter `-WhatIf` to the `Rename-Item` command to *preview* the renaming operation.

Note that `Rename-Item` always renames items in their current location; to (also) move them, use `Move-Item`.

If a target with the same name already exists, `Rename-Item` reports a non-terminating error for each such case (without aborting overall processing).
Note that his could also happen if an input filename contains no `-`, as that would result in attempt to rename a file to itself.

**Explanation:**

- `Get-ChildItem -File` outputs `[System.IO.FileInfo]` objects representing the files in the current directory, which are passed through the pipeline (`|`) to `Rename-Item`.
- Passing a script block (`{ ... }`) to `Rename-Item`'s `-NewName` parameter executes the contained code for each input object, where `$_` represents the input object at hand.

  - Note that this virtually undocumented but frequently used technique is called a script-block parameter [value], where a parameter that is designed to take pipeline input can be bound with a script block that processes the input indirectly.
- `($_.BaseName -split '-')[0]` extracts the 1st `-`-separated token from each input filename's base name (filename without extension).
- `+`, because the LHS is a string, performs *string* concatenation.
- `$_.Extension` extracts the filename extension  from each input filename.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a PowerShell thing. If you just want something to work, this is a cmd batch file thing.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "OLDDIR=C:\Users\lit\files"
SET "NEWDIR=C:\Users\lit\newdir"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`DIR /A:-D /B "%OLDDIR%\*"`) DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=- tokens=1" %%b IN (`ECHO %%a`) DO (SET "BN=%%b")
    SET "EXT=%%~xa"
    ECHO COPY /Y "%OLDDIR%\%%~a" "%NEWDIR%\!BN!!EXT!"
)
```